# Clone HD using Symantec Ghost Solution Suite 2.5

Tags: windows-sbs-2003, symantec, ghost, windows-server-backup

All I want to do is a simple Hard drive clone on my Windows 2003 SBS. Last time I used this software is was a pain in the neck having to mount it on a different server and run a Ghost Cast. Is there a way to just clone the primary HD onto another one in the same way you can with Norton Ghost products?

If not, can you recommend a version of Norton Ghost that will work on SBS 2003 to simplify this process somewhat?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *thought* there was a version of the old `ghost32.exe` included with the Ghost Solution Suite products. This tool is a lot like the old DOS-based `ghost.exe` and will let you perform local disk-to-disk, disk-to-image, etc, clones. I don't know that it will clone from a booted system volume, though, so you may gave to use WinPE / BartPE to boot the machine to use the software but, assuming you do it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

GHOST is not a solution for doing a hot/running image of the SBS.  Symantec System Recovery 2011 is a good solution.  It can backup the entire system and then restore it to different hardware. Convert to a VM and it also makes a great general backup solution hot/running if tape is not used.  Free eval here [Sysetm Recovery Overview](http://www.symantec.com/business/system-recovery-small-business-server-edition)  Perhpas not teh one step you asked for but generally pretty quick and easy